# How to express the sum of a set?

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have a set of numbers. How can I express in set-theory terms the sum of the elements in that set?

Comment: Something like $\sum_{x\in A}x$, or do you want to ask how to sum numbers in axiomatic set theory rigorously? That would depend very much on how you define numbers.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker actually that's pretty much what I need. I just didn't know that was "legal syntax" in set theory. Thanks!

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with set theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no set-theoretic notation for that since a sum of numbers (presumably real or complex numbers, but more generally could be elements in a ring) is not a set-theoretic notion.

If the numbers you have are indexed by some set, that is if you have a function $f:I\to \mathbb R$ (just taking the reals here to simplify things), then (if $I$ is finite), the sum of the multi(!)set $\{f(i)\mid i\in I\}$ is commonly denoted by $\sum_{i\in I}f(i)$. If $I$ is infinite then some limiting notion is required to make sense of the sum.